# Alternate of WHMCS

Tags: billing, whmcs, accounting

Alright, I know there might have lots of answers for that but I need some real suggestion on which I can depend. Can anyone please suggest me a free script for billing which is stable, user-friendly and have maximum features?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check [HostBill](https://hostbillapp.com/). It can be used for billing and managing your servers.

Answer (score 1):

While free is nice, I still would definitely recommend going with WHMCS to manage your billing/clients

While these are free and opensource, I really wouldn't recommend them. They're pretty basic. Trust me, it's worth paying for a license for WHMCS instead

[TheHostingTool](https://thehostingtool.com/download)

[ShineISP](http://shinesoftware.github.io/shineisp/)

Test them carefuly

Answer (score 1):

I've been using WHMCS for years. Its the best. And you can get a FREE license with many hosting providers ([Namhost.com](http://www.namhost.com) being one i know of). They also offer a free license for WHM Autopilot on certain packages.

But your other options are:

1. [ClientExec](https://www.clientexec.com/) (not free, but only 12 USD)
2. [WHM Autopilot](https://whmautopilot.com/) (not free, but only 15USD)
3. [Box Billing](http://www.boxbilling.com/) (free)

Answer (score 0):

WHMCS is no more working in UBUNTU 14.04 or any other surrounding using PHP 5.5 and they wrote that it might take months until they release first betas!!!

he people from ioncube wrote:

> we cannot offer a solution at this time ... Again, this is not a
>   deliberate restriction, but rather a result of PHP's tremendous
>   changes in their execution engine. For now the only fix for you
>   appears to be to downgrade for PHP 5.4.

And WHMCS wrote

> Exactly, so as of our next major release we will no longer be
>   supporting PHP 5.2 so that we can encode using the version of Ioncube
>   which supports PHP 5.3 and above. The current version of WHMCS still
>   supports PHP 5.2, so at this time it isn't possible for us to
>   distribute a single copy which supports 5.2 and 5.5+.

and

> I can advise that we will not be releasing v6.0 this weekend, a beta
>   is expected in the next few months.

better use another solution before loosing your customers ;-)

Comment: Though reliably supporting files designed for now end of life PHP versions (5.0 in this case) is tricky and may be impossible due to the significant changes in the PHP engine, and providers *should* be giving customers files built for PHP 5.3+ (or even better, PHP 5.4+) so that end users can enjoy benefits such as better performance, PHP 5.5 and 5.6 support etc., ionCube have dedicated fresh resources to explore supporting old files. If this pans out and the work passes the stringent QA process then we should see support for PHP 5.0 files on 5.5 soon.  Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.